# Unable to pass color variable in included layout using Data Binding

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding

I want to pass a variable of color to included layout, currently, I'm trying to pass color from my colors.xml and I've added variable type `'android.graphics.Color'` but it's not working, what should be the type of variable for Color in exact?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="isLoading"
            type="Boolean" />
        <variable
            name="loaderColor"
            type="android.graphics.Color" />
    </data>

    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_loading_indicator"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_loading_indicator"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="@{isLoading?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
        app:indicatorColor="@{loaderColor}"
        app:indicatorName="LineSpinFadeLoaderIndicator" />
</layout>
```

main layout

```
<include
                    layout="@layout/layout_btn_loading_indicator"
                    app:loaderColor="@{@color/theme_color}"
                    app:isLoading="@{viewModel.isLoading}" />
```

Comment: `@color/fayvo_color` is an int. Let me know if it fixes your issue

Comment: Thanks, it really helped a lot.

Comment: yes, it may help someone else in a clear way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@color/color_name` is a resource Id and, therefore, has type is `int`. Your variable should be like

```
<variable name="loaderColor" type="int" />
```

Comment: yes, right but why it works with variable type String for @string/title . shouldn't it also be int?

Comment: Indeed. Colors are always 4bytes int tho. String, on Android can be represented either by a res-id or a string object itself